# How to configure Jax-WS with Spring 3 using annotations only?

Tags: spring, web-services, jax-ws

I failed to access the url http://localhost:8080/mn_webapp/CustomerService?wsdl

with this configuration below :

```
@Configuration
@ImportResource({ "classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml"})
public class ContextConfig extends SpringBootServletInitializer {   
    @Bean 
    public ServletRegistrationBean dispatcherServlet() {        
        return new ServletRegistrationBean(new CXFServlet(), "/*"); 
    } 
    @Autowired
    private Bus cxfBus;     
    @Bean 
    public EndpointImpl endpoint() { 
        EndpointImpl endpoint = new EndpointImpl(cxfBus, applicationContext.getBean(IWCustomerService.class) ); 
        endpoint.publish("/CustomerService"); 
        return endpoint; 
    }     
}
```

and the web.xml

```
  <context-param>
      <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
      <param-value>   
   org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
      </param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>com.dev.core.init.ContextConfig</param-value>
  </context-param>        
  <listener>  
      <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>  
     </listener>
```

it seems that dispatcherServlet() and endpoint() are never called?

Comment: Well no and why should it... If you want to configure a servlet you need a `WebApplicationListener` or plain `ServletContainerInitializer` it will not work in a web application context (unless you are using spring boot).

Comment: i am folowing this doc http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jaxrs-services-configuration.html#JAXRSServicesConfiguration-ConfiguringJAX-RSservicesprogrammatically and the use the same config in web.xml

Comment: so what is the correct web.xml config?

Comment: No you aren't following that doc, if you would you would have noticed that is the Spring Boot and not the plain Spring configuration. With Spring boot you don't have a web.xml.

Comment: The doc cleary has sections for Spring and Spring Boot and you are trying to use the second one in a plain spring application.

Comment: ok i add SpringBootServletInitializer and remove CFx servlet config, but still not working, i modify my question